# R: How do I scale this plot?

Tags: r, plot

In the plot resulting from this next code:

```
plot(poll$reality, poll$seker,xlab = "reality", ylab = "poll")
text(poll$reality, poll$seker, rownames(poll), cex=0.7, pos=3)
abline(0,1)
```

I can't seem to be able to scale the to axes to look the same, an so I get the feeling that the 'abline' (which is supposed to be a simple x=y) is misplaced.
I tried using 'plot.window' but couldn't quite understand how it worked as it had no affect.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `plot(..., asp = 1)`. This should force the 1:1 ratio of axes.